# Passing 2 generics in Priority Queue

Tags: java

I want to keep two things in my priority queue...one is a number and the other is cost. i.e. I want to do the following:

```
PriorityQueue<Integer, Cost> q=new PriorityQueue<Integer, Cost>();
```

Cost is another class that i hav:

```
class Cost implements Comparable<Cost>
{
  String name;
  double cost;

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Cost s)
  {
    return Double.compare(cost, s.cost);
  }
 }
```

Also I want to perform comparisons only based on cost...but I also want some integer identifier to be passed along with cost...is there some way to achieve this?

i need to retrieve Cost based on id..therefore I am using a hash map for it. When using an id field in cost...i want to retrieve the entire cost instance based on that id field...is it possible...is yes, then how?

I am a novice at Java programming. Can someone pls suggest some way out?

Comment: You could add an `id` instance field to `Cost`.

Comment: ya..but i need to retrieve Cost based on id..therefore I am using  a hash map for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `Cost` class

```
public class Cost implements Comparable<Cost> {
    String name;
    double cost;
    int id;

    public Cost(int id, String name, double cost) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Cost s) {
        return Double.compare(cost, s.cost);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder().append("id : ").append(id).append(
                " name: ").append(name).append(" cost :").append(cost)
                .toString();

    }
}
```

Then you can simply declare `PriorityQueue` of `Const`

```
PriorityQueue<Cost> q=new PriorityQueue<Cost>();
```

Now when you want to find `Cost` based on `id` you can do below

```
PriorityQueue<Cost> queue = new PriorityQueue<Cost>();
    queue.add(new Cost(1, "one", 1));
    queue.add(new Cost(2, "two", 2));
    int id = 2;// Id to be found
    for (Cost cost : queue) {
        if (cost.getId() == 2) {
            System.out.println(cost);
        }
    }
```

Comment: When using an id field in cost...i want to retrieve the entire cost instance based on that id field...is it possible...is yes, then how?

Comment: @user1593063 You will have to iterate and compare for `id` else you can provide equals on `id` but then it will break contracts of equals and comparable to provide equals on other field and compareTo on another

Comment: can u please explain...with an example

Comment: SO community will kill me if I give you example like that. It is better in your case to iterate over it and check if id matches.

Comment: oh..is that so..but i have seen other forms also..where people give examples to illustrate their point...also for iterating over the ids..the ids need to be stored somewhere..

Comment: @user1593063 check the example

Answer (score 0):

The `Cost` object is a good start.  Make an object that contains both an integer and a `Cost`, and put *those* in the priority queue.  Or, add an integer field to the `Cost` class itself.

Comment: ya..true..can u pls elaborate with an example

Answer (score 0):

You may want to wrap your integer and cost in a `Map/HashMap` as below:

```
   PriorityQueue<Map<Integer, Cost>> q = new PriorityQueue<Map<Integer, Cost>>();
```

Now you would be able to create a HashMap object and put you two object in that before putting in the queue.

Also, you want to create a **custom  wrapper Class** e.g. `CostNumber` which will have Integer and Cost as two member variables. Once done ,you can use that new object in the queue.

Comment: but will the method poll still do comparisons based on Cost..that is what i am doubtful about

Comment: "Also, you you want to create a custom wrapper Class e.g. CostNumber which will have Integer and Cost as two member variables. Once done ,you can use that new object in the queue." I didnot get u..can u pls explain with an example.please

Comment: @user1593063: If you use custom class, you may want to enhance the `comapreTo` method.

Comment: @user1593063 It won't; you could create a custom map implementation with a compare to check for the cost objects. EDIT: Nevermind that makes no sense. There's really only one reasonable approach: an `id` field in Cost.

Comment: @Vulcan Ya true...can u pls illustrate how to do the same with custom hashmap with an example

Comment: @user1593063 I can't, because it's not a feasible approach.

Comment: @Vulcan When using an id field in cost...i want to retrieve the entire cost instance based on that id field...is it possible...is yes, then how?

Comment: Actually, why are you using a PriorityQueue if you want to get costs based off of their ids?  Sounds like a map will better suit you entirely.

Comment: @Vulcan correct map suits me..but the problem still remains..i want to do comparisons based on Cost..that is what i am doubtful about

Answer (score 0):

Since PriorityQueue stores a single object, you need to do one of the following:

- create a class that contains both the integer and the cost object, iff integer and cost are unrelated.
- push the integer attribute as another member of Cost class iff they are related.

> Also I want to perform comparisons only based on cost...but I also want some integer identifier to be passed along with cost...is there some way to achieve this?

Why would you want to pass something to compareTo that you are not going to use during comparison? In any case, the signature of this method cannot be changed if you want to leverage the Comparator framework. You can add that integer identifier to your Cost class itself as another member and thereby make it available during compareTo method execution.